# Redux A state mutation was detected before reach the reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm sending from the view to an action this.props.appClasses
This is the view:

```
 <div key={key} className='SDWanAppClassTreeItem' onClick={this.props.actions.handleToggleAppClass.bind(this,this.props.appClasses, 0, key)}>
```

In the action I modify appClasses that I get from the view, I want to send appClasses modified to the reducer to update the appClasses state. But it gives me an error before reach the reducer.

> A state mutation was detected
>   This is the action:

```
export function handleToggleAppClass(appClasses, parentAppClassId, appClassId) {
  // console.log('handleToggleAppClass', appClassId, this.appClasses[appClassId]);

  if (appClass.parentAppClassId == 0) {
    // Flip the appClass Show Property
    appClasses[appClass.appClassId].show = appClasses[appClass.appClassId].show ? false : true;

    if (Object.keys(appClasses[appClass.appClassId].children).length !== 0) {
      // Regardless if we enable or disabled the parent, all children should be disabled
      for (var childKey in appClasses[appClass.appClassId].children) {
        appClasses[appClass.appClassId].children[childKey].show = false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    // If we are enabling a child, make sure parent is disabled
    if (!appClasses[appClass.parentAppClassId].children[appClass.appClassId].show) {
      appClasses[appClass.parentAppClassId].show = false;
    }
    appClasses[appClass.parentAppClassId].children[appClass.appClassId].show = appClasses[appClass.parentAppClassId].children[appClass.appClassId].show ? false : true;
  }

  dispatch(handleUpdateInitialSourceFetch(appClasses));

  return { type: types.TOGGLE_APP_CLASS, appClasses };
}
```

As you can see, I do want to modify appClasses on the action because I have to use the newly modified appClasses to update another state on another reducer. Here I want to modify appClasses state (which is in one reducer) and by dispatching the modified appClasses in the function call onother action dispatch(handleUpdateInitialSourceFetch(appClasses));
I want to modify another state selection.appClassesIds (in another reducer that handles user selections):

```
const selection = {
  timespan: "-3660",
  direction: 0,
  appClassIds: []
};


export function updateAppClassesIds(appClasses) {
  var appClassIds = [];
  for (var key in appClasses) {
    if (appClasses[key].show) appClassIds.push(key);
    if (Object.keys(appClasses[key].children).length !== 0) {
      // Regardless if we enable or disabled the parent, all children should be disabled
      for (var childKey in appClasses[key].children) {
        if (appClasses[key].children[childKey].show) appClassIds.push(childKey);
      }
    }
  }

  return { type: types.UPDATE_APP_CLASSES_IDS, appClassIds };
}
```

How can I send the appClasses variable from the view to the action without getting that error.
Or should I put selection and appClasses state in one big state to be able to get access to both states because they depend on each other?

Comment: Is `appClasses` already in the state? I.e., are you mutating state directly?

Comment: Yes is a state that I get from this.props.appClasses

Comment: You must not mutate state directly; that's one of the main philosophies of Redux. In general, this transition would be represented not by setting the entire array here, but by passing an ID and its new state. In the reducer you'd copy the old state and splice in the new app class state.

Comment: I know, but I need what that variable to send to the action, It can be a copy or something like that, I read from a post that somebody did something like const a = [...this.props.appClasses] but didn't work. How can I send that values of that variable?

Comment: (Moving comment to answer for formatting reasons.)

Comment: Can I use all that logic to modify the state, that I use in the actions inside the reducer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134101/discussion-between-diego-unanue-and-dave-newton).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating an action that receives the ID of the appClass to modify and the new value (true/false).

Your reducer should then be able to handle the updates to your state which will then propogate through subscribed components.

Comment: (This is more or less what I said in the comment, but omits the part of the comment discussing slicing/etc, which is what the OP is having difficulties with.)

Comment: I want appClasses accesible in the action to update another state in another action that depends on appClasses using a dispatch(handleUpdateInitialSourceFetch(appClasses)); Should I combine appClasses and selection.appClassIds in one reducer. Because they depend one to each other. And I can send the id of the appClass but there's a lot of logic as you can see in the function can I put all that logic in the reducer?

Answer (score 0):

What I'm saying is that the appropriate payload for something that "toggles an app class" isn't an entire list of app classes, but something closer to:

```
{ 
    type: types.TOGGLE_APP_CLASS, 
    payload: appClass.appClassId
}
```

State modification should be done in the reducer–that's explicitly [what reducers are for](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#handling-actions).

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the next state.

You're trying to (a) modify the state directly in an action creator, and (b) attempting to modify state in the wrong place. Once you start doing stuff in the right place, it's a lot easier to fix this.

In your reducer you'd either `slice` (if this is an array) or do an object clone to update the single toggle and set the state to this new copy of state. But you do *not* mutate state directly; doing so would break a lot of what Redux is bringing to the table (time-travel, for example).

Comment: As you can see I'm trying to modify appClasses there because I want to use it to update another state "selection.appClassIds
" that needs appClasses modified sending dispatch(handleUpdateInitialSourceFetch(appClasses)); maybe I think that I must have selection.appClassIds and appClassesId on one big state in one reducer. And please also see that the modifications are complex I thought that only the actions should hanldle that amount of code to modify a variable, then send this var modified to the reducer and update the state. I update my question with the complete code.

Comment: I'm converting the app from altjs to redux, so I'm so lost, can I make all those changes to the state in the reducer?